# How to add looping in DetailView Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Ok, this maybe simple. I want to add looping in my DetailView in Yii2.
Example :

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'atasan',
            'value' => /*I want to add looping here*/
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

How can I do that? Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: add related code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version **2.0.11** `value` can be an **annonymous function** aswell, so:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'atasan',
            'value' => function($model) {
                  $example = '';
                  foreach($model->atasan as $atasan) {
                        //here your stuff
                        $example .= 'Oh God, it looped again. '; 
                  }
                  return $example;                // here's returned value
            }
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

Just remember, that this anonymous function **should `return` a value**, not echo or anything.